# C program iterates too much when using fork inside while

Tags: c, fork

I'm reading lines of text from file, and for each line I'm processing it using several { fork() --> child process invokes execvp(), and parent invokes wait() } .
at the end of process I'm writing the results to a file.

Problem is: the while loop seems to iterate too much and also the writing to the file.

The results.csv file contains 6 lines instead of just 2 (the while iteration
iterates a text file with 2 lines, but also when I use printf it seems like the last line is read twice).

What am I missing here?

The code example is:

```
FILE* results = fopen("results.csv", "w");
if (results == NULL){
    fclose(fp);
    perror("Failed opening results file");
    exit(-1);
}
fdIn = open(inputPath, O_RDONLY);
if (fdIn < 0){
    perror("Failed opening input file");
    exit(-1);
}
while (fgets(student, sizeof(student), fp) != NULL) {
    // override end line char of unix ('\n') with '\0'
    student[strlen(student)-1] ='\0';
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        close(fdIn);
        perror("Failed creating process for executing student's program");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {// son process code
        fdOut = open("tempOutput.txt", (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC), 0666);
        if (fdOut < 0){
            perror("Failed opening temporary output file");
            exit(-1);
        }
        close(1);
        dup(fdOut);
        close(fdOut);
        close(0);
        dup(fdIn);
        close(fdIn);
        char studProgPath[bufSize];
        strcpy(studProgPath,studentsFolderPath);
        strcat(studProgPath,"/");
        strcat(studProgPath,student);
        strcat(studProgPath,"/");
        strcat(studProgPath,"a.out");
        char * args[] = {"a.out", NULL};
        ret_code = execvp(studProgPath,args);
        if (ret_code == -1){
            perror("Failed executing student program");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    waited = wait(&stat);
    if (stat == -1){ // need to grade 0
        printf("%s,0\n",student);
    }else{ // open process to compare the output with the expected
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0){
            perror("Failed opening process for comparing outputs");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(pid == 0) { // son process
            char * args[] = {"comp.exe",outputPath,"tempOutput.txt",NULL};
            ret_code = execvp("comp.exe",args);
            exit(ret_code);
        }
        waited = wait(&stat);
        if (stat == -1) {
            perror("Failed executing comparing program");
            exit(-1);
        } else if (stat == 0 || stat == 1) { // if outputs are not the same
            fprintf(results,"%s,0\n",student);
        } else { // matching outputs grade 100
            fprintf(results,"%s,100, pid: %d\n",student,getpid());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to test the return value from `execvp()` (or any other `exec*()` function).  If the function is successful, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.

Comment: What does the `a.out` program do with its standard input?  It's a bit surprising that you redirect the file input to the standard input of what becomes the `a.out` process.  You don't print an error if the `comp.exe` process fails.  Until you know what's wrong, that should be printed — and probably even after you know what's up.

Comment: You should also fclose(fp) and fclose(results) before the first execvp. Also, should flush results before each fork, or after the fprintf and before the next fork

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the a.out is reading from the stdin, so I redirected it to my input file.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler but I need to write to the results.csv file from the main process, so I keep it open.

Comment: @ovedmani what I mean is that you should close it in the child only, after flushing it before the fork. Closing in the child doesn't close it in the parent

Comment: @MichaelVeksler thanks for your answer. I tried closing both and it didn't work. how do I flush the "results.csv" before each fork?

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Thanks! your answer to fflush before each child solved it. I wanted to rate your answer but option is disabled.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can duplicate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `fclose(fp);
    perror("Failed opening results file");`  The call to `fclose()` modifies the value in `errno`, so the call to `perror()` is not accessing the reason the call to `fork()` failed.  Suggest swapping those two lines.  Similar considerations exist for other calls to `perror()`

Comment: regarding: `waited = wait(&stat);
        if (stat == -1) {`  the failure status is placed in the `waited` variable, not in the `stat` variable

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `dup(fdOut);`  This duplicates the file descriptor `fdOut` and returns the new/duplicated file descriptor, However, the code is not saving that new file descriptor,  something like: `int newFD = dup( fdOut );`

Comment: regarding: `student[strlen(student)-1] ='\0';`  For various reasons, including there not being a '\n' at the end of the input, This will destroy the data.  Suggest:  `student[ strspn( student, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `ret_code = execvp("comp.exe",args);
    exit(ret_code);`  immediately after the call to `execvp()` should be a call to `perror()` and none of the `exec*()` functions return anything when successful and return -1 when failed so `exit(ret_code)` is meaningless.  Should be `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249: regarding not capturing the return value from `dup()`.  The code does `close(0)` and then calls `dup(fdIn)`; it knows that `dup()` will return 0.  Similarly with `close(1); dup(fdOut)`.  If there is no open stdin when the `close(1)` is called, then `dup()` will return 0 instead of 1.  However, that's not a plausible scenario; programs are entitled to assume file descriptors 0, 1, 2 are connected to appropriate channels.

Comment: @ovedmani you can accept the answer below, not grade the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The file which gets triple entries gets opened here:

> ```
> FILE* results = fopen("results.csv", "w");
> ```

The following lines write to this `results` file, slightly before the function calls `fork()`:

> ```
> } else if (stat == 0 || stat == 1) { // if outputs are not the same
>   fprintf(results,"%s,0\n",student); 
> } else { // matching outputs grade 100 
>   fprintf(results,"%s,100, pid: %d\n",student,getpid()); 
> }
> ```

This file should be flushed with `fflush(results)` before the fork, otherwise the buffer of `results` might be flushed three times: in the parent, and in the two copies in the children.

Also, `results` and `student` should be closed with `fclose(results)` and `student`, before calling execvp. If the files are not closed, then the `a.out` might manipulate the `results` file. I assume that `a.out` is an external code which you don't control.

```
while (fgets(student, sizeof(student), fp) != NULL) {
    // override end line char of unix ('\n') with '\0'
    student[strlen(student)-1] ='\0';
    fflush(results); // otherwise each child may flush the same chars
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0){
        fclose(results); // otherwise ./a.out might write to this file
        fclose(fp); // better also close it.
        close(fdIn);
```